# Apache2 mod_rewrite possible bug?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory named 'foo' within my virtual host root. I am trying to intercept requests for a non-existent file also called 'foo' and rewrite them to a PHP file, the .htaccess file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on   
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /foo
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php [L]    
</IfModule>
```

All I keep getting back from the server on a GET request for '/foo' is a 301 redirect to '/foo/' (the directory). Why is Apache doing this before processing the rules? Am I missing a configuration option? Or can this not be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 301 redirect is coming from the [DirectorySlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) directive that is part of [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html).

I suspect your `.htaccess` is not working due to one or both of:

1. You have `AllowOverride` configured to not allow `.htaccess` files.
2. The `.htacess` file is *inside* the `/foo/` directory, so mod_dir applies its 301 redirect before the `.htaccess` file is processed.

Comment: The DirectorySlash directive was the configuration that I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Remember the Filesystem Always Takes Precedence**

The filesystem on your server will always take precedence over the rewritten URL. For example, if you have a directory named “foo” and within that directory is a file called “router.php”, you can’t have the URL redirect to “http://domain.com/foo”. What happens is that Apache goes into the “foo” directory and doesn’t see the rewrite instructions.

To fix this, simply rename your directory (adding an underscore to the beginning or end is a simple way to do that).